# The device is temporarily restricted

Tags: java, android, app

Привет.

Не удается включить USB отладку и установку через USB. Выбивает ошибку, указанную в заголовке. Отключение Wi-Fi и включение вместо него моб. данных не помогает.
Модель Xiaomi Redmi Note 4X, Android 7.0 NRD90M, MIUI Global 9.0.

Comment: Developer options -> USB debugging включили в телефоне?

Comment: Отладка по USB включена, но "Установка через USB" и "USB отладка (Настройки безопасности)" выдают одну и ту же ошибку.

Comment: Установку из неизвестных источников разрешили? Безопасность -> Администрирование устройства

Comment: Да, установка разрешена.

Comment: Попробуйте отключить [оптимизацию MIUI](http://c.mi.com/thread-162468-1-1.html)  в Developer options ->

Comment: Не помогает. Может быть, еще один важный факт: на ПК устройство отображается только лишь как "Портативный проигрыватель".

Comment: у вас там в шапке отображается "подключен как ....."? Перейдите в раздел "память", что там?

Comment: Если Вы имеете ввиду шапку уведомлений, то там относительно отладки два сообщения: одно - зарядка устройства, второе - USB debugging connected.

Comment: устройство может подключаться как медиа-устройство , камера, только зарядка. Вытащите усб и ставьте в телефон обратно, там появится как он подключен и посмотрите

Comment: По дефолту он подключает как зарядку. Хотя в конф. USB выставлен MTP. При подключении также выбираю передачу файлов. Выбор конфигурации "передача файлов" открывает как "внутренний общий накопитель" для ПК, но доступа к Установке через USB и USB отладке так и не дает.

Comment: Может вам драйвер-usb нужно установить? [ADB Driver Lite (32/64-bit) for Redmi Note 4X](https://xiaomifirmware.com/downloads/download-drivers-utilities-redmi-note-4x/)

Comment: Нет, он установлен.

Comment: Может имеет смысл вернуть смарт? Ему всего пару дней..

Comment: Можно, как вариант, снести miui и поставить что-то на основе aosp. Но только гарантия, вроде, слетает. Да и не каждому понравится. Я со своим китайцем так и поступил.

Comment: Блин, ну гарантию терять не круто. Я вот и думаю.
Я сейчас написал на форум MIUI и в оф. группу Mi в ВК. Если в течение нескольких дней решение не найдется, пойду в магазин, разираться с ними.
Ну а так.. насчет оригинальности: IMEI и S/N вроде совпадают, значит девайс от офиков. Будем ждать.

Comment: В общем, я так немного полазил по телефону, и нашел еще парочку багов: так, например, я не могу загрузить в свой Mi аккаунт фотографию: выбивает "Не удается подключиться к сети", хотя соединение с сетью есть. Полагаю, что, если в схожих ситуациях (проблемы с USB отладкой) некоторым пользователям MIUI помогало переключение интернета с Wi-Fi на мобильные данные, то проблема кроется в неадекватной прошивке, которая не может понять, есть ли соединение с сетью. К тому же плюсом идет то, что не активируется СИМ, хотя в слоте она стоит и звонки я совершать могу.
Завтра вернусь в магазин, там решим.